# What can cause a dask distributed future to have the state 'lost'?

Tags: python-2.7, distributed, dask

Using a dask distributed cluster, I've noticed, that several of the futures of long running tasks switch from `pending` to `finished`, others switch from `pending` to `lost`.

I have the suspicion, that some of the `lost` tasks are still running, as I see `dask-worker` processes with a high CPU usage even if no futures have the status `pending` anymore.

What exactly does `lost` mean here? Can long-running tasks (hours) be classified as `lost` as they might stop the worker from reporting back to the scheudler? What else could cause the state `lost` and how does the scheduler react to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that for some reason the scheduler no longer has the information necessary to execute this task.  Commonly this is due to non-resilient data being lost by a worker going down, such as if you explicitly scatter a piece of data to a single worker and then that worker fails.

```
>>> future = client.scatter(123)
>>> x = client.submit(f, future)

 ... worker holding future/123 dies

>>> x.status
'lost'
```

This is rare in general though.  Usually if a worker goes down the scheduler can replicate all of the work for a particular task elsewhere.

As always, providing a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) can help to isolate what's going on in your particular situation.

Comment: Does the scheduler has a mechanism to figure out whether the worker is alive even though the worker is occupied with long running tasks and if so - how does it work?

Comment: Probably, you ask about "heartbeat"  which is used to check workers and compare time.

Comment: The worker and scheduler communicate on a separate thread from the computation.  Performing a long-running task doesn't prevent administrative from moving around.